# Is a linked list in a struct possible?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am working on an assignment that deals with storing and sorting some data. I had an idea to create a simple data structure as follows:

```
struct names 
{
char username[9];
linked list of structs
}

struct login
{
char ip_addr[16];
int count;
}
```

I have my linked-list of login structs working properly, however, I am unsure as to how I would go about inserting a linked-list of structs into a different linked-list of structs. Is it even possible?

Comment: Well, first, "what is a linked list"? How can a linked list be named (e.g. what variable *type* can it be assigned to)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, put the header node pointer inside your `names` struct.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I was struggling with that. Thanks @shan.